# Need help to understand the derivation of Union of Square of 2 sets

Tags: trace

I was reading [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_monoid).

And got stuck understanding this derivation:

> Consider the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$. A possible dependency relation is
>   \begin{array}{ccc}
> D&=&\{a,b\}\times\{a,b\}\quad\cup\quad\{a,c\}\times\{a,c\}\\
> &=&\{a,b\}^2\cup\{a,c\}^2\\
> &=&\{(a,b),(b,a),(a,c),(c,a),(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)\}.
> \end{array}

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U4ma.png)

How can a union of square of 2 sets derived to the 3rd line?

PS: I'm not from Maths background.

Comment: Do you know what the square of a set is?

Comment: @James Yes. If it is one and the same thing mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: Indeed, so $\{a,b\}^2 = \{(a,b),(b,a),(a,a),(b,b)\}$ and $\{a,c\}^2 = \{(a,c),(c,a),(a,a),(c,c)\}$ and so their union is just all of these put together.

Comment: hey I got it. I just need to reorder them all. but Thanks anyways.

Comment: "*I just need to reorder them all...*" technically you don't because for sets order is unimportant.  The set $\{1,2,3\}$ is the same as the set $\{3,1,2\}$ and $\{2,1,3\}$.  When order matters, we call it an **ordered set**.

Comment: Gotcha. What you meant. Thanks a lot.